# Separate NewRelic Application for each ASP MVC Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, newrelic

I'm trying to split ASP MVC areas into separate applications within New Relic.
Within each area I have created a new web.config file that simply contains the below XML.  This doesn't seem to be creating a new application like I would expect it to.

It works when it is in the root web.config.  I don't have this key in the root config of this MVC application, however.

Any help would be appreciated - otherwise it might just be something that cannot be done?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="My Area Name" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Relic .NET agent can only gather settings from a web.config file in the app root.  Unfortunately, there isn't a way to set NewRelic.AppName on the fly using the API or specify a path for per-app config files.  You might write into support@newrelic.com and submit a feature request.

Comment: They have been very helpful in feature requests in the past - thanks @nr-wyatt